# Swift - TableView crashing when scrolling back up

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have been struggling with this issue. I can scroll freely between the tag cells because it actually remembers them. But if I get the description cell out of my view it immediately removes it from memory and doesn't get it back. Instead I just get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when I scroll back to the description. So I have the following pieces of code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I don't know if the viewWillAppear is of any importance in this case but if it is then tell me. Anyway, this is for filling in the cells in my table view:

```
func GetDescription(cell:descCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.descText.text = descriptTextTwo.htmlToString
}

func GetTagCell(cell:basicTag, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let item = tagResults[indexPath.row]!
    cell.titleLabel.text = item["tagname"]?.htmlToString
}

func GetValueCell(cell: basicTag, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let item = tagResults[indexPath.row]!
    cell.valueLabel.text = item["value"]?.htmlToString
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if filledDescription == false {
        return getDescriptionAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    } else {
        return getTagAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }
}

func getDescriptionAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> descCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(descriptionCell) as descCell
    GetDescription(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    filledDescription = true
    return cell
}

func getTagAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> basicTag {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(tagCell) as basicTag
    GetTagCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    GetValueCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

So how can I make Swift remember what is in the first cell? Because I am guessing that that is what happens, that it removes what was in the first cell as soon as you get it out of the view. I am guessing I have to do something with "indexPath" but I am not exactly sure how to implement it in this case and if I am far off, please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: For which line do you get the error ?

Comment: I don't get an error. The app builds and launches. It's not untill I am in this view and start scrolling down and then back up that the app crashes.

Comment: But if your device is launched via Xcode you should see a crash log with a trace giving you the last line of execution before the crash occurs... do you see one?

Comment: Yes and as stated in the question the only thing I get is "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following :

```
 if filledDescription == false {
     return getDescriptionAtIndexPath(indexPath)
 } else {
     return getTagAtIndexPath(indexPath)
 }
```

With:

```
 if indexPath.row == 0 {
     return getDescriptionAtIndexPath(indexPath)
 } else {
     return getTagAtIndexPath(indexPath)
 }
```

This will make sure that the first cell in the table will always treated as a **"Description"** cell. Since the `filledDescription` never becomes `false` after your set it to `true`, when you get back to the first cell it is treated as a **"Tag"** cell (due to the `if` line) where in fact the reusable cell contains **"Description"** cell data